# how to retrieve properly Json content form asp.net web-service function using angularJs vs Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, angularjs

I am pretty new with `AngularJs`, and I am taring to get `json` content with `AngularJs` from asp.net `web Service` by using `WebMethod` function
and i am getting `Error 500`

asp.net:

```
[WebMethod]
public string jasonTemp()
{
    BLFrontend.Frontend BLFrontEndHendler = new Frontend();
    BindingList<Product> ProductListHendler = BLFrontEndHendler.ListOfProducts();
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProductListHendler, Formatting.Indented);
    return json;
}
```

JavaScript:angular - Controller:

```
webStoreControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/WebStoreWSToHTML.asmx/jasonTemp').success(function (data) {
        $scope.products = data;
    });
}]);
```

but when I am using `Ajax` it's working properly

JavaScript:Ajax:

```
function callSvc1() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebStoreWSToHTML.asmx/jasonTemp",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status) { alert(data.d); },
        error: function (request, status, error) { alert(request.responseText); }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use `console.log(data)`  to see what you get

Comment: you should not misuse the return value `string` to inject a json-string. this is by no means safe, as there is no contract followed (just implicitely). you should rather return an object and let your webservice framework of choice handle the serialization (such as seviceStack) ...

Comment: can you give me an example to learn what are you mean?

Comment: what is the exception on the server-side?

Comment: i don't have .. and it is working great with Ajax and no errors

Comment: SO is no HOWTO-forum unfortunately, but to give you an idea: usually you return an object that the webservice framework serializes in a format it supports (usually xml). doing your own serialization is a misuse of the "framework"-idea and you should rather look into options how to enable JSON and let the framework do the serializaiton. btw ... ASMX has already been deprecated in favor of WCF - but, personally, I would suggest looking into ServiceStack...

Comment: @avis If you are getting an internal server error, there *is* a server-error. which one?

Comment: "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/jasonTemp'."

Comment: so you are telling me that using WCF it safer way?

Comment: safer?... I am saying that your misuse of a webservice framework is a problem. that has nothing todo with WCF.

Comment: thank you Andreas  i will learn about  ServiceStack